# how can make an event on wpf user control element just element not all the user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls

i have a C# user control named "Body_US" contains some elements such as label, images

[image: as shown here].

I used the user control many times in main_window.

The problem is just i wanted to add an event on the image inside the user control.

For example when clicking on the image the opacity decreases .

How can i access the image inside the user control and make the event ?

Comment: Have you not got access to the User Control's code? If you do then access it through an event on an image element, otherwise you need to contact whoever created that user control to expose that element. Otherwise a behaviour would fit in nicely here [Behaviours](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)

Comment: i have an access to the user control but the event i want to make is related to the code not stand alone event .